# "stdin: is not a tty" from cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm getting the following mail every time I execute a specific cronjob. The called script runs fine when I'm calling it directly and even from cron. So the message I get is not an actual error, since the script does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Here is the cron.d entry:

```
* *     * * *     root   /bin/bash -l -c "/opt/get.sh > /tmp/file"
```

and the get.sh script itself:

```
#!/bin/sh

#group and url
groups="foo"

url="https://somehost.test/get.php?groups=${groups}"

# encryption
pass='bar'
method='aes-256-xts'
pass=$(echo -n $pass | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/&/g')

encrypted=$(wget -qO- ${url})
decoded=$(echo -n $encrypted | awk -F '#' '{print $1}')
iv=$(echo $encrypted | awk -F '#' '{print $2}' |base64 --decode | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/&/g')

# base64 decode input and save to file
output=$(echo -n $decoded | base64 --decode | openssl enc -${method} -d -nosalt -nopad -K ${pass} -iv ${iv})

if [ ! -z "${output}" ]; then
        echo "${output}"
else
        echo "Error while getting information"
fi
```

When I'm not using the `bash -l` syntax the script hangs during the wget process. So my guess would be that it has something to do with wget and putting the output to stdout. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Yes I do use a proxy set through the http_proxy variable.

Comment: Oh, wait I think we are getting somewhere here. I set the proxy through a file in /etc/profile.d Which gets included through /etc/profile. Maybe this just isn't available during a "normal" cronjob call?

Comment: Make sure that the variable is set when your bash (user root) is no login shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually have two questions here.

1. Why it prints `stdin: is not a tty`?

This warning message is printed by `bash -l`. The `-l` (`--login`) options asks `bash` to start the login shell, e.g. the one which is usually started when you enter your password. In this case `bash` expects its `stdin` to be a real terminal (e.g. the `isatty(0)` call should return 1), and it's not true if it is run by `cron`—hence this warning.

Another easy way to reproduce this warning, and the very common one, is to run this command via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh user@example.com 'bash -l -c "echo test"'
Password:
stdin: is not a tty
test
```

It happens because `ssh` does not allocate a terminal when called with a command as a parameter (one should use `-t` option for `ssh` to force the terminal allocation in this case).

2. Why it did not work without `-l`?

As correctly stated by @Cyrus in the comments, the list of files which `bash` loads on start depends on the type of the session. E.g. for login shells it will load `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` (see INVOCATION in manual `bash(1)`), while for non-login shells it will only load `~/.bashrc`. It seems you defined your `http_proxy` variable only in one of the files loaded for login shells, but not in `~/.bashrc`. You moved it to `~/.wgetrc` and it's correct, but you could also define it in `~/.bashrc` and it would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

in your .profile, change

```
mesg n
```

to

```
if `tty -s`; then
  mesg n
fi
```

Comment: Here's the explanation for this solution: You have to check that stdin is terminal before using `mesg`.

Comment: Where is .profile? If it is the one present in home directory then there is no `mesg n` in my file

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the proxy configuration in the wgetrc. There is now no need to execute the script on a login shell anymore.

This is not a real answer to the actual problem, but it solved mine.

If you run into this problem check if you are getting all the environment variables set as you expect. Thanks to Cyrus for putting me to the right direction.