# "stdin: is not a tty" error on git pull

Tags: git

I try to pull change from a remote repository but it doesn't work anymore.

When I type `git pull` and I enter the password, I'm still getting this `stdin: is not a tty`.

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please use more descriptive subject for your post.

Comment: Can you post the full error given by `git`? Do you manage to clone the repository successfully?

Comment: `git clone` doesn't work too

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of git? What kind of URL? (It probably is an ssh URL and you see an ssh error.) What happens if you simply try to ssh to that host?

Comment: I use Mac on local, `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`, it's a SSH url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157703/stdin-is-not-a-tty-from-cronjob

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue while committing or pushing to github. See log:

```
$ git push
stdin is not a tty
error: failed to push some refs to https://...
```

I was able to fix the problem by upgrading the git hooks created by husky:

```
$ npx husky
```

I'm using the following versions:

- git: 2.24.1.windows.2
- husky: 4.0.0
- mintty 3.1.0 (x86_64-pc-msys)

Related issues/pull-requests:

- Issue: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/627
- Pull request: https://github.com/typicode/husky/pull/634

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, add this to your `.bashrc`, before sourcing global `/etc/.bashrc`, so pretty much the top.  This is especially for cpanel shared hosting.

```
# Prevent "stdin: is not a tty" errors
if [ $(expr index "$-" i) -eq 0 ]; then
    return
fi
```

Not only will the error disappear, you will then also see the output error.

Comment: I wonder why this question or the answer have got no votes... This works for me. If I interpret it right, the line stops the execution of the bashrc script if it is not interactive, i.e. `$-` does not contain "i".

Comment: You can also do use the expression `tty -s` instead, which directly checks whether the shell is interactive.

Answer (score -1):

This error message is coming from the remote repository. The remote does not have a `tty` or interactive terminal configured on `stdin` when handling `git` commands over SSH. There are many reasons this could be the case but it shouldn't be interfering with your ability to clone or pull. I would just try to enter your password.