# Crontab does not work properly

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I have a script /root/restart-container-name

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/docker restart container_name 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/docker exec -ti container_name /path/launcher.sh 2>/dev/null
```

Without cron it works.
in crontab work only first command. The second does not working.

Permission 700 and owned by root

I redirect stderr into file /tmp/container_name.log. The error is

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you see already tries to explain what's wrong. As you specified `-t` to the exec command, it tries to allocate a TTY. When run from cron, there is no pseudo-TTY available and thus it fails.

Try to change your script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/docker restart container_name 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/docker exec -i container_name /path/launcher.sh 2>/dev/null
```

FYI: There are a lot of questions regarding cron and TTY here. For example, this one explains the problem pretty well: ["stdin: is not a tty" from cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157703/stdin-is-not-a-tty-from-cronjob)