# Bash showing error while installing platformsh CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash

I tried to install CLI with curl way. but it’s showing error. Check the below image.
[image]

Can anyone please help? not sure what to do.
If anyone knows how to install psh cli, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

how did you open your terminal?

There is a related question to your error message here:

["stdin: is not a tty" from cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157703/stdin-is-not-a-tty-from-cronjob)

I think your problem could be related to your terminal/bash session.

Comment: I use a normal git bash. Do I need to open it in a different way? cause on Github they just mentioned to use that command to install CLI.